# Summation of the trigonometric series

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\alpha$ is the exterior angle of a regular polygon of $n$ sides , prove that  $$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin (\theta+ \alpha r ) = 0\; .$$

Comment: I might help to notice $\alpha = \frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Sorry it was 0 there instead of  question mark

Comment: Related: [How can we sum up $\sin$ and $\cos$ series when the angles are in arithmetic progression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro)

Comment: U can get this formula by searching in internet easily

Answer (score 1):

So, we need to prove that for every $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(\theta+\alpha r)=0$$
Actually, we will prove something stronger; that the some apllies for $\cos$ as well:
$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos(\theta+\alpha r)=0$$
Now, at first, note, as Alex Vong pointed out, that $\alpha=\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Now, the idea of the proof is quite geometric. Let us consider the following vectors on the Cartesian plane:
$$\vec{v_r}=(\cos(\theta+\alpha r),\sin(\theta+\alpha r)),\ r=0,1,\dots,n-1$$
These form, as one can see, a regular polygon inscribed in the unitary circle. For our ease, we will use complex numbers to make use of some elementary properties of complex multiplication. So, using Euler's formula:
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$$
we can describe each of our vectors $\vec{v_r}$ as a complex number. More precisely:
$$\vec{v_r}\mapsto e^{i(\theta+\alpha r)}$$
Now, let us sum these vector:
$$\begin{align*}
S&=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i(\theta+\alpha r)}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i\theta}e^{i\alpha r}=\\
&=e^{i\theta}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i\alpha r}=e^{i\theta}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\left(e^{i\alpha}\right)^r\tag{Geometric sum}\\
&=e^{i\theta}\frac{1-\left(e^{i\alpha}\right)^n}{1-e^{i\alpha}}=\\
&=e^{i\theta}\frac{1-e^{2\pi i}}{1-e^{i\alpha}}=\\
&=e^{i\theta}\frac{1-1}{1-e^{i\alpha}}=\\
&=0
\end{align*}$$
Now, note that:
$$S=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{i\theta+\alpha r}=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos(\theta+\alpha r)+i\sin(\theta+\alpha r)=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(\theta+\alpha r)+i\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos(\theta+\alpha r)$$
But, a complex number is zero exactly when both it imaginary and real part are zero, so:
$$S=0\Leftrightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\sin(\theta+\alpha r)=0\\
\displaystyle\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\cos(\theta+\alpha r)=0
\end{array}\right.$$
So, the requested has been proved.

Comment: Thanks for solving the requested question. But let me know how the vectors vr= cosine(theta+r) ,sin(theta+r) is forming the sides of regular polygon in uninary circle

Comment: Well, at first $|\vec{v_r}|=\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta+ar)+\sin^2(\theta+ar)}=1$. So, all these points are on the circumference of the unitary circle. Then, let us find the angle $\phi$ between $\vec{v_r}$ and $\vec{v_{r+1}}$. We know that, since they are of unitary length: $$\cos(\phi)=\vec{v_r}\cdot\vec{v_{r+1}}=\cos(\theta+ar)\cos(\theta+ar+a)+\sin(\theta+ar)\sin(\theta+ar+a)=\\=\cos(\theta+ar+a-(\theta+ar))=\cos a$$ so the angle between two consecutive vectors is exactly the internal angle of a regular polygon with $n$ sides.

Comment: You 're wellcome! :)